# Why do I have an error "[Header] is not a <Route> component."?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a social media app and my App.js looks like this:

```
<div className="App">
      <Router>
        {!name ? (
          <>
            
            <Login />
          </>
        ) : (
          <Routes>
            <Route exact path="/">
              <Header />
              <Feed />
              <Model />
            </Route>
            <Route exact path="">
              <Navigate to="/" />
            </Route>
          </Routes>
        )}
      </Router>
    </div>
```

So if user is authorized it redirects us to the main page but if they're unauthorized, we have a Login page.

But I have the next error in console:

```
Uncaught Error: [Header] is not a <Route> component. All component children of <Routes> must be a <Route> or <React.Fragment>
```

What causes this error?

Comment: Try wrapping up `Header`, `Feed` and `Model` within a `<></>` tag

Comment: What version of react-router-dom are you using? This is significant now as V 6 has a new way of doing things

Comment: i did it and even added React.Fragment, but the error still remains

Comment: @DimitarVeljanovski i use v6 as you could by "Routes", but could the version cause the error?

Comment: if you are using V6 then why do you still use `exact`? AFAIK that is no longer required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In version 6 of react-router, you're expected to use the `element` prop to tell it what to render:

```
<Route path="/" element={(
  <>
    <Header />
    <Feed />
    <Model />
  </>
)}/>
```

Adding children to a route is reserved for defining nested routes, as in:

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
  <Route path="users" element={<Users />}>
    <Route path="/" element={<UsersIndex />} />
    <Route path=":id" element={<UserProfile />} />
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

Comment: thanks, it worked! but now i have the same error with "Navigate", should i use the same method? because Navigate is a part of react-router-dom

Comment: Yes, use the `element` prop for that too.

Comment: Im not out here crying for reputatuon but my answer was posted a full minute before this guy's and pretty much details the exact same thing.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an older version of react-router-dom:

```
<Route exact path="/" component={(
    <React.Fragment>
          <Header />
          <Feed />
          <Model />
    </React.Fragment>
)} />
```

If you are using V6, replace the name of the `component` prop with `element` and that will do it.

As of V6, all children of `Route` or `Routes` MUST be a `Route`. If you have for example a route with `path="/home"` and you have route `/home/abc` then the route`/abc` should go inside of the `/home` route as a child to its `Route` component.

Doesn't fully make sense to me why they chose this way of doing this, but hey, the community doesn't matter, right? :)